# Como enviar xml a un webservice con PHP

Tags: php, xml, webservice

En esta ocasión estoy haciendo el **REQUEST** para obtener un **RESPONSE** de un webservice, pero al mandar mis parametros me arroja un error, el cual menciona que mi nombre de usuario no debe ser vacío o nulo.

adjunto mi codigo de entrada:

```
<?php

try {


$soapclient = new soapclient('http://frecuenciacotizador.estafeta.com/Service.asmx?wsdl');

 $sh_param = array( 
                    'idusuario'    =>    '1',
                    'usuario'    =>    'Ejemusuario',
                    'contra'    =>    'Ejemplopass',
                    'esFrecuencia' => 'false',
                    'esLista' => 'true',
                    'EsPaquete' => 'true',
                    'largo' => '10',
                    'Peso' => '10',
                    'Alto' => '10',
                    'Ancho' => '10',
                    'datosOrigen' => '54463',
                    'datosDestino' => '02719');
 $headers = new SoapHeader('http://frecuenciacotizador.estafeta.com/Service.asmx', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);



$response = $soapclient->FrecuenciaCotizador();

var_dump($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

y adjunto la imagen con el error que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis parámetros de acceso fueron otorgados por la paqueteria a la cual le pertenece el webservices.

Alguien podría orientarme en como colocar mis parámetros de acceso?

Comment: Parece que no estás enviando los encabezados, prueba a poner esto: `$soapclient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);`

Comment: Esa línea de código, ya la había colocado anteriormente y me imprime un error, el cual es el siguiente:
Fatal error: Call to a member function __setSoapHeaders() on null in C:\AppServ\www\estafeta\index.php on line 23
el error lo identifica en la linea de codigo:
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
de ahi ya no encuentro alguna solución para mitigar el error

Comment: Entonces parece que es el cliente el que no se está creando.